# How to select and/or store a column from user file Upload and use it to subset a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

So I am creating this feature in R shinyApp where a load a large dataframe

Reproducible Example: 
Large dataframe

        `name      start        end      party
 1 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
 2    Kennedy 1961-01-20 1963-11-22 Democratic
 3    Johnson 1963-11-22 1969-01-20 Democratic
 4      Nixon 1969-01-20 1974-08-09 Republican
 5       Ford 1974-08-09 1977-01-20 Republican
 6     Carter 1977-01-20 1981-01-20 Democratic
 7     Reagan 1981-01-20 1989-01-20 Republican
 8       Bush 1989-01-20 1993-01-20 Republican
 9    Clinton 1993-01-20 2001-01-20 Democratic
10       Bush 2001-01-20 2009-01-20 Republican
11      Obama 2009-01-20 2017-01-20 Democratic` `

and prompt the user to upload a file.

user Input file:
      `state     name    party 
      Illinois  Obama   Democratic
      Texas     Bush    Republican
      Arkansas  Clinton Democratic`

I would like to access a particular column of the uploaded file (in this case 'name') and use it to subset my larger data frame and display the smaller data frame back to the user as a data table.

Resulting Data Frame:
      `name      start     end        party
9     Clinton  1993-01-20 2001-01-20 Democratic
10       Bush  2001-01-20 2009-01-20 Republican
11      Obama  2009-01-20 2017-01-20 Democratic`

So far I have only the code for selecting user input and displaying the original data table:

ui:

```
ui =  fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                    accept=c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv")
          ),
          tags$hr(),
          checkboxInput("header","Header",TRUE),
          radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                       c(Comma=',',
                         Semicolon=';',
                         Tab='\t'),
                       ','),
          radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                       c(None='',
                         'Double Quote'='"',
                         'Single Quote'="'"),
                       '"')
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput("contents")
        )
      )
    )
```

server:

```
output$contents <- renderTable({
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)

data = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)})

presReact <- reactive({
    return(prestable)})

 output$prestable = renderDataTable({
    DT::prestable(presidentData())})
```

Comment: Do you mean to save the file? You could just use `shiny::reactiveFileReader` once uploaded. Otherwise, you can manipulate with your `fileInput` however you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you kindly elaborate in more detail. I have added my code and would like to know how fileInput can be manipulated to access the column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading in a file in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922126/reading-in-a-file-in-r-shiny)