# Use loaded file as input to function in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing a shiny web app that aims to:

- Load a file
- Parse the file **once** using a function `myDummyFun`
- Use the returned dataframe `d` as input to plotting functions across multiple tabs

This is a simplified version of what I'm doing that illustrates the problem (although uses the `mtcars` dataset in place of a loaded file:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(
    # Tab 1
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Upload your file"),
              sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Browse for your file')
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 renderDataTable('contents')
               )
              )

    ),

    tabPanel("Plot",
             pageWithSidebar(
               headerPanel('Example plot'),
               sidebarPanel(),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput('plotExample')
               )
             )
    )
  )
)
```

---

```
myDummyFun <- function(x){
  x <- x %>% 
    filter(disp<=400) 

  return(x)
}
```

---

```
server <- function(input, output, server) {

  observe({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    # I am really using the loaded file as input: 
    # d <- myDummyFun(inFile$datapath)
    d <- myDummyFun(mtcars)

  })

  # datatable of data
  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    renderDataTable(d)
  })

  # tabPanel 1 
  output$plotExample <-renderPlot({
    ggplot(d) +
      geom_point(aes(disp, mpg))

  })
}
```

---

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My parsing function `myDummyFun` is actually quite large, and takes a while to read in the selected file `input$file1`, so **I want to read the file once, and then have the returned data frame accessible by each plotting function**.

In this example, **`d` is locally scoped, and therefore not accessible by `renderDataTable(d)` or `renderPlot`**. What is the correct way of organising this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help for observe `?observe` says:

> An observer is like a reactive expression in that it can read reactive
>   values and call reactive expressions, and will automatically
>   re-execute when those dependencies change. But unlike reactive
>   expressions, it doesn't yield a result and can't be used as an input
>   to other reactive expressions. Thus, observers are only useful for
>   their side effects (for example, performing I/O).

And the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922126/reading-in-a-file-in-r-shiny) supposes to nest the `output$something` calls inside the `observe` structure.

Therefore I think your `observe` should look like:

```
  observe({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    # I am really using the loaded file as input: 
    # d <- myDummyFun(inFile$datapath)
    d <- myDummyFun(mtcars)
    output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
      renderDataTable(d)
    })

    # tabPanel 1 
    output$plotExample <-renderPlot({
      ggplot(d) +
        geom_point(aes(disp, mpg))

    })
  })
```

When commenting out the `if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)` part this app also runs and the plot looks like

[image]

And for completeness, the full code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(
    # Tab 1
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Upload your file"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Browse for your file')
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 renderDataTable('contents')
               )
             )

    ),

    tabPanel("Plot",
             pageWithSidebar(
               headerPanel('Example plot'),
               sidebarPanel(),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput('plotExample')
               )
             )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
myDummyFun <- function(x){
  x <- x %>% 
    filter(disp<=400) 

  return(x)
}

function(input, output, server) {

  observe({
    inFile <- input$file1

    # if (is.null(inFile))
    #   return(NULL)
    # 
    # I am really using the loaded file as input: 
    # d <- myDummyFun(inFile$datapath)
    d <- myDummyFun(mtcars)
    output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
      renderDataTable(d)
    })

    # tabPanel 1 
    output$plotExample <-renderPlot({
      ggplot(d) +
        geom_point(aes(disp, mpg))

    })
  })

  # datatable of data

}
```

Hope this helps.